# Why doesn't the class have a getter key?

Tags: javascript

```js
class Class3 {
  get service() {
    return 'service'
  }
}

const class3Instance = new Class3()
console.log(class3Instance.service)
console.log(class3Instance)
//  clas3Instance had Semi transparent service

var descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(class3Instance, 'service')
console.log(descriptor, "descriptor")
//  undefined
```

I expected `class3Instance` has service property but it didn't.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like any methods defined directly inside a `class`, it's a property on the *prototype*, not on the object itself. Check the descriptor of `Class3.prototype`, or of `Object.getPrototypeOf(class3Instance)`:

```js
class Class3 {
  get service() {
    return 'service'
  }
}
const class3Instance = new Class3()
var descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Class3.prototype,'service')
console.log(descriptor,"descriptor")
```

The `class3Instance` object does not have an *own property* of `service` - when `class3Instance.service` is accessed, the interpreter finds that property name on the internal prototype of `class3Instance`, not on `class3Instance` itself.

Comment: Is there a way to declare getter such that it goes on the instance (like the new [public/private fields](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields))?

Comment: Pretty sure no, `get` can't be put anywhere in there without throwing an error, and a special descriptor is needed. One silly method would be `#doNotUse = (() => { Object.defineProperty(this, 'service', { get() { return 'value' } }) })()`